# Need to create a diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm new with Tikz package and now need to create a diagram like this:

[image]

But, I don't know how to make vertical lines in each node.

This is the code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (2,0);
    \coordinate (D) at (10,0);

    \draw[|-|] 
        (A)
        node at (A) [above=5pt] {$P_{t,M}$} 
        node at (A) [below=5pt] {$t$}
        --
        (B)
        node at (B) [above=5pt] {$C$} 
        node at (B) [below=5pt] {$t+1$}
        --
        (C)
        node at (C) [above=5pt] {$C$} 
        node at (C) [below=5pt] {$t+2$}
        --
        (D)
        node at (D) [above=5pt] {$C+N$}
        node at (D) [below=5pt] {$t + M$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Really appreciate any help!Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have already defined the coordinates (B and C) of the point, a `foreach` loop seems to be the natural choice:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1,0);
\coordinate (C) at (2,0);
\coordinate (D) at (10,0);

\draw[|-|] 
(A)
node at (A) [above=5pt] {$P_{t,M}$} 
node at (A) [below=5pt] {$t$}
--
(B)
node at (B) [above=5pt] {$C$} 
node at (B) [below=5pt] {$t+1$}
--
(C)
node at (C) [above=5pt] {$C$} 
node at (C) [below=5pt] {$t+2$}
--
(D)
node at (D) [above=5pt] {$C+N$}
node at (D) [below=5pt] {$t + M$};

\foreach \x in {B,C}
\draw ($(\x)+(0,2pt)$)--($(\x)+(0,-2pt)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that I used the `calc` library, but you have other ways to achieve the same result:

```
\foreach \x in {B,C}{%
   \draw (\x)--++(0,2pt);
   \draw (\x)--++(0,-2pt);
}
```

Or also (which is a compact version)

```
\foreach \x in {B,C}
\draw (\x)--++(0,2pt) (\x)--++(0,-2pt);
```

Comment: Woowww. Welcomeeeeee...Claudio. Do you remember me? I'm Sebastiano the professor that a few years ago asked you to certify the use of LaTeX. Obviously I voted +1 your answer. A very strong hug.

Comment: @Sebastiano Sure, I remember very well:) Hope everything is going on well. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

You could split the path (this way, you can be sure that the ticks are all the same):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
%\begin{center} % not really useful in standalone class
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  [every node/.style={text depth=0pt}] % align node text
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (2,0);
    \coordinate (D) at (10,0);

    \draw[|-|] 
        (A)
        node at (A) [above=5pt] {$P_{t,M}$} 
        node at (A) [below=5pt] {$t$}
        --
        (B);
    \draw[-|] 
        (B)
        node at (B) [above=5pt] {$C$} 
        node at (B) [below=5pt] {$t+1$}
        --
        (C);
     \draw[-|]
        (C)
        node at (C) [above=5pt] {$C$} 
        node at (C) [below=5pt] {$t+2$}
        --
        (D)
        node at (D) [above=5pt] {$C+N$}
        node at (D) [below=5pt] {$t + M$};
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]